# Create Drag Drop Pegman Using OpenLayers 4

Tags: openlayers, geojson

Here is a fiddle of my progress: http://jsfiddle.net/pegues/a5mn1ogu/

I've been trying to figure out how to create a drag and drop marker using OpenLayers like what is found with Pegman in Google Maps. I've successfully added a marker to the page, either on page load or by clicking a button. But I need to actually duplicate the behavior identical to how Google uses Pegman at maps.google.com to load streetviewer. I have no idea how to proceed with producing this behavior.

I've tried using HTML5 drag behavior, but that doesn't work:

```
document.getElementById('pegmanButtonDiv').addEventListener("dragstart", function(e) {...}
```

There are no examples similar to pegman with drag and drop markers at: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/

I was successfully able to use interact.js to be able to implement drag and drop (interactjs.io#drag-and-drop), but this is independent of the OL canvas. I'm at the point where I need define the interact.js DOM element as an OL marker, then when dragged and dropped capture the coordinates where the marker was dropped in the OL map. Perhaps I also need to load a GEOJSON file to specify the bounding box region in interact.js?